# How can I enforce the recurrence relations of SphericalHarmonics?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Spherical harmonics satisfy a number of recurrence relations as reported [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/SphericalHarmonicY/17/01/01/). How can I enforce them in order to simplify a complicated relation like this one:

```
Cot[x] (-D[-Sin[x] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, x, y], x], x] + 
    D[Sin[x] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, x, y], x], y]) - 
 D[(-D[-Sin[x] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, x, y], x], x] + 
    D[Sin[x] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, x, y], x], y]), x]
```

It should be possible to rewrite the result in terms of $Y_{lm}(x,y)$ but the expression returned by Mathematica includes terms proportional to $Y_{lm+1}(x,y)$ and $Y_{lm+2}(x,y)$